# Why the TCP client haven't receive the ACK response, it send the FIN package?

Tags: tcp, networking

I use the WireShark captured the TCP connect.

you see the three-way handshake(1-3) and the four-way handshake(5-8):

[image]

But, from the frame list, I have a question about TCP.

You know the TCP should use ACK sign to get the response, no matter the `ack` for `syn`, or `ack` for data send.

you see the 4rd frame, the `192.168.187.1` send the message to `192.168.187.129` [PSH, ACK].

1. but the `192.168.187.1` haven't get a ACK, it send the FIN package to `192.168.187.129`, why?
2. in the 5rd package, can it send the [FIN] package directly? why there need the [FIN, ACK]? why can not send the [FIN]?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. RFC 793 indicates that:

> > FIN

> A control bit (finis) occupying one sequence number, which
> indicates that the sender will send no more data or control
> occupying sequence space.

If the sender has no more data to send, it sends a packet which its `FIN` flag is set.
If the receiver doesn't receive data, it will send a duplicate `ACK` to the sender.

So the sender waits for a time and if it doesn't receive acknowledgment of the `FIN` or data within this time, or if it receives a duplicate `ACK`, it will retransmit the packets.

2. `ACK` control flag is always sent once a connection is established; As RFC 793 says:

> Acknowledgment Number:  32 bits

> If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the
> next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to
> receive.  Once a connection is established this is always sent.

**Edit:** So until the connection is not established, packets can be sent without `ACK`.

For example, when one side of the connection sends `SYN` packet and doesn't receive any acknowledgment; in this case, it can send a `FIN` packet without `ACK`, since there is nothing to acknowledge it.

[RCF793:3.5.  Closing a Connection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5) also indicates that:

> The user who CLOSEs may continue to RECEIVE
> until he is told that the other side has CLOSED also.

Sending `ACK` will tell to the sender that which sequence number is expected to receive and it prevents extra retransmissions that occur because of `ACK` lost.

---

Edited based on @ron-maupin 's comment.

Comment: "_`ACK` control flag is always set to `1` once a connection is established;_" You misinterpreted the quote. The acknowledgement number is always sent one a connection is established, but the `ACK` flag is only sent when there is actually something to acknowledge. In most cases, the `ACK` flag is always sent because each side needs to acknowledge something from the other, but there are cases where one side is only acknowledging what the other side is sending, and the sending side has nothing to acknowledge from the other side. The acknowledgement number tells the other side what is expected.

Answer (score 2):

> but the 192.168.187.1 haven't get a ACK, it send the FIN package to 192.168.187.129, why?

Apparently, 192.168.187.1 has finished sending and is closing the socket. That is entirely normal.

> in the 5rd package, can it send the [FIN] package directly? why there need the [FIN, ACK]? why can not send the [FIN]?

FIN and ACK are combined in a single segment, this is completely normal as well. The flags are sent in a bit field, so they can be combined to avoid sending extra segments for each status change.

Comment: Can it only send the [FIN] not [FIN, ACK]?

Comment: It's possible, but it's customary to use any opportunity to ACK the received data, even if it's redundant.

Comment: @244boy, the side sending the `FIN` is also acknowledging what was sent to it. In theory, if there was nothing to acknowledge, then a `FIN` could be sent alone. There is a chart on page 23 of [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-23) that explains the flow. Also, [Section 3.5.  Closing a Connection](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-3.5) clearly explains how connections are closed using `FIN`..